# Magnetic Dipole: How to plug into Maxwell's equations?

Tags: electromagnetism

I read [Magnetic Dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole) point source in computational electro-magnetic literatures where it is used as exciting source. But I do not know how to plug this source into [Maxwell's equations](http://www.spec2000.net/06-electromag.htm).

Does it go into the free electric current density $J_f$?

Does the point dipole gives a Dirac function somewhere in Maxwell's equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A source producing a magnetic dipole solution of the maxwell equation is
given by the following (free) current distribution

$$\mathbf{J} =  -\mathbf{m} \times \mathbf{\nabla} \delta^3(x)$$

(Without free charges)

This current gives rise to the vector potential

$$ \mathbf{A}(x) = \int \frac{\mathbf{J}(x')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}d^3x' = \frac{\mathbf{m} \times \mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|^{3}}$$

Where the integration is immediate due to the delta function.

This current source can be viewed as a small plane current loop of current $I$ and
radius $a$, such that the plane of the loop is perpendicular to the
vector  $\mathbf{m}$, in the  limit $a \rightarrow 0$ and $I
\rightarrow \infty$ such that:

$$ m = \frac{\pi I a^2}{c}$$

The relation of the magnetic dipole moment $m$ and the current can be obtained from equating the magnetic field on the loop axis computed by the Biot-Savart law: $B = \frac{2\pi I a^2}{r^3}$ to that given by the magnetic dipole formula $B = \frac{2m}{r^3}$.

Comment: Is $m$ the length of vector $\mathbf{m}$? In the limit $a\rightarrow0$ and $I\rightarrow\infty,$ why you got $m$ still involving $I$ and $a$?

Comment: Is $\nabla \delta^3(x)$ gradient of point Dirac function?

Comment: @Hui Zhang Yes it is the gradient of a delta function. $m$ is the magnitude of the magnetic dipole moment vector. You can choose the radius of the loop $a$ tending to zero, the current $I$ tending to infinity, but the combination $I a^2$ finite, for example by taking $I =\frac{I_0}{\epsilon^2}$ and $ a = a_0 \epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. A similar trick is performed in the case of an electric dipole.

Comment: Is the electric current source equivalent to some magnetic current source like this: $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{B}+\mathrm{curl}\,\mathbf{E}=-\frac{d\mathbf{m}}{dt}{\delta}^3(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: If magnetic charges would exist in Maxwell equations: $\mathbf{\nabla}.\mathbf{B} = 4 \pi \rho_m$ where $\rho_m$ is the magnetic charge density, then the magnetic dipole solution can be obtained exactly in the same way an electric dipole is obtained in the standard Maxwell theory; i.e., by taking two opposite infinitesimally spaced magnetic charges.

Comment: Let us assume magnetic charges exist :) Could you please tell me how to insert $\nabla \mathbf{B}=4\pi\rho_m$ to the curl equation $\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dt}+\mathrm{curl}\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{J}_m,$ where I want the expression for magnetic current $\mathbf{J}_m$ corresponding to the magnetic dipole.

Comment: A magnetic current loop will give rise to an electric dipole and not a magnetic dipole solution, the same way that an electric current generates a magnetic dipole in the example above. These are the only solutions known to me to generate a magnetic dipole: 1) An electric current loop, 2)Two opposite magnetic charges.

Comment: It seems that I can take $\mathrm{div}$ on the 'curl E' equation to get $\nabla\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{B}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}_m$ then substituting $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=4\pi\rho_m$ gives $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}_m=4\pi\frac{d\rho_m}{dt}.$ Now how can I solve out $\mathbf{J}_m$?

Comment: You reached the (magnetic) continuity equation (the $4 \pi$ factor should not be there). The two solutions considered above automatically satisfy the (electric and magnetic) continuity equations. In the electric loop case, the sources satisfy $\mathbf{\nabla}.\mathbf{J}_e = 0$ and $\rho_e = 0$. In the magnetic charge case $\frac{\partial \rho_m}{\partial t} = 0$. (The charges are time independent) and $\mathbf{J}_m = 0$. I don't see an easy way to generate a magnetic dipole from a magnetic current.